# jQuery sortable mouse cursor jumps when enter placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a little problem.

Here is my config for sortable (written in coffee):

```
$('.sortable-column').sortable({
  helper: 'clone',
  handle: 'i.icon-move',
  revert: 500,
  containment: 'body',
  tolerance: "pointer",
  cursorAt: {right: 10, top: 10}
  forceHelperSize: true,
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  distance: 3,
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  start: @dragStart,
  update: @sortUpdated,
  stop: @dragStop
  connectWith: ".sortable-column"
}
```

I have multiple sortable columns. The main problem occures when dragged helper enters any placeholder ( sortable column ). In this moment it simply jumps more to the top out of the cursor.

So now I have lets say cursor about (depends on the height of the target element) 250px bellow the helper. 
And the big problem is, that even after the calling the refreshPositions() method in sortUpdated or dragStop , it keeps this distance above the cursor when I try to dragged it again.

It looks like that during the dragging, when it could be dropped in the sortable, it will try to reposition it to the top level (instead of sorted it) but then I loose the sync with mouse cursor and it will never came back no matter what. So it has some cache or something, which according the doc the refreshPositions() should clear, but it doesn't.

Am I missing something or did I forget some settings?

Comment: Finally I worked this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451528/jquery-ui-sortable-scroll-helper-element-offset-firefox-issue/20225012#20225012

This helps.