# Jquery Sortable Bug: wrong top + left offset for dragged item every first time after being initialized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am experiencing a weird `sortable` bug:

[image]

everytime I clicked on `Manual`, It will `append()` the `Manual` tab `html`, which is a `sortable` `<ul><li></li> ... </ul>` list

[image]

after that if I drag any `<li>` item ( Example `Item 2` ), the dragged element `left` + `top` offset values are wrong the first time:

[image]

if the dragged element is moved vertically to another position or stopped draggin, it works as expected

[image]

this is the javascript code snippet for the `sortable` list:

```
var tab_html = '<ul id="featured-sortable">'+
    '  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>'+
    '  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>'+
    '  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>'+
    '  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>'+
    '  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>'+
    '  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>'+
    '  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>'+
    '</ul>';


// Append New Last Child
$(this).closest('div.setting-item').append(tab_html);

/*
|==========================================================================
| Featured sortable
|==========================================================================
*/
$( function() {

    $( "#featured-sortable" ).sortable({
        // cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 },
        start: function(e, ui)
        {
            console.log('ui.offset: ' + JSON.stringify(ui.offset, null, 2));
            console.log('ui.position: ' + JSON.stringify(ui.position, null, 2));
            console.log('ui.originalPosition: ' + JSON.stringify(ui.originalPosition, null, 2));

            let target = $( event.target );

            console.log('target.css(top): ' + target.css('top'));
            console.log('target.css(left): ' + target.css('left'));

        },
        sort: function(e, ui)
        {
            let target = $( event.target );

            console.log('target.css(top): ' + target.css('top'));
            console.log('target.css(left): ' + target.css('left'));

            // ui.originalPosition.top = target.css('top');
            // ui.originalPosition.left = target.css('left');
        }
    }).disableSelection();


} );

// Refresh Featured-Sortable
$( "#featured-sortable" ).sortable( "refresh" );
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this was fixed by adding

```
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
```

on the parent element. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451528/jquery-ui-sortable-scroll-helper-element-offset-firefox-issue) for a similar issue